# Windows 8 Google Contacts Sync doesn't sync custom fields

Tags: windows, windows-8, contacts

I installed Windows 8 Pro a couple days ago. In the in-built "People" app, since there were options to sync contacts with several third party services like Facebook, Linkedin etc., I wanted to sync my Google contacts to the People app.

The sync was successful and all my contacts migrated properly.

However, the age old problem of custom fields not syncing between Google/Apple/Windows apps is still present.

If a field label in my Google contacts is 'iPhone', it doesn't sync! Nor do any other custom fields except 'home' or 'work' with numbers.

Is there a solution to this or any other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Google uses [Google Sync](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=135937), which uses Microsoft® Exchange ActiveSync® to sync contacts, mail, and calendars.  Unfortunately, this protocol does not support syncing some of the custom fields which are available in the Google Contacts application.  I'm not sure of the exact mapping Google uses, but [these are the fields Exchange ActiveSync supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee160254%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).

Some workarounds you could use would be:

- Use the Notes field to synchronize all your custom data.
- Ensure that phone numbers you want to sync always use the built in labels.  Based on Outlook.com, they are:

  - Mobile
  - Mobile 2
  - Home
  - Home 2
  - Work
  - Work 2
  - Other
  - Company
  - Pager
  - Work fax
  - Home fax

[image: Phone Types on Outlook.com]

Comment: Google has discontinued support for Google Sync for free accounts.  If you had not already set it up, you won't be able to set it up, so while this answer is valid its no longer possible to implement.